# How do I fix this huge gap on the top of my website?

Tags: html, css

There's a huge gap on the top of my [website](https://wonderlustgames.com/) and I'm not sure what I need to edit to make it disappear. It was working fine up until a few days ago when I updated my Wordpress version and theme (bizconsulting).

This is the only additional CSS I have used:

```
h4, h1{
    visibility:hidden;
}

h2{
    color: white;
}

div.page-area{
    visibility:hidden;
}

div.copyright{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Define `huge gap` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not wish to keep the head banner saying "Infinite Mana - Wonderlust Games, A 2.5D RPG with a huge world, unique classes and glitch mechanics."
Then use `display:none` on it:

```css
.page-area.home_banner_section {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a bunch! I was using "visibility:hidden".